# Question about archaisms

Tags: vocabulary

I have a few questions about archaisms! Can anybody give examples of

1. semantic archaisms (I need 5 examples) I found only one about the word "fair" and I really can't find anything else!
2. grammatical archaisms (I need 3 new  examples) I have already found examples with hath ‘has’, thou/thee ‘you’, thy  ‘your’.

Or, if  I am asking to much, maybe you can recommend some resources? I know, that there are a lot of vocabularies in the Internet, but there is no information about categories.

(I mean, I can't understand, is it a semantic archaism or phonetic archaism?)

There is no difficulties to systematize archaisms in my native languages, but as for the foreign it's very hard!

Comment: You've gotta be kidding me.

Comment: Sorry, if i seemed rude.I am just really confused with this theme.

Comment: Do a search on Shakespeare's vocabulary, and look for words such as "honest" (not given to infidelity), "stout" (brave), etc. Next time _please_ check your spelling, syntax, grammar, and punctuation to the best of your ability. I have no idea what phoentic means. I do know what phonetic means, but I'm not a mind reader, nor should I be obligated to _decipher_ anything. The word "I" is _always_ capitalized. Use a computer, not your phone. Have some respect for others: it's called good manners.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but still  I can't understand how it will help me to sistemize archaisms, because I have exampels (there are plenty of them in the Internet), but there is no information about categories.I am using my computer, not my phone.As for my English, I do my best, and if you don't have time to read bad written question, just skip it!Thank you again!

Comment: This has nothing at all to do with your English. Didn't I just say "to the best of your ability"? Anything _less_ than that is rude. I daresay you do know how to spell "I" and "phonetic." As for your question, I'll give it a shot shorty.

Comment: @Ricky Actually with a smartphone you're far more likely to have correct spelling and capitalization than on a computer. Rather than the spelling being incorrect, there would instead be a different word than what you meant. If you have to type something manually it means either the phone is too stupid to pick up what you mean (or, interpreted another way, you can't make a precise enough gesture) or the word is just not in its dictionary. The dictionary is quite large.

Comment: @MattSamuel: Thank you. I stand corrected. "Your brain," not "your computer." Or something. I'll apologize in a sec.

Comment: My apologies. You're not using your phone. That's a good thing!

Comment: I fixed phoentic.

Comment: @deadrat: That sounds ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

The way I see it, ***semantic*** archaisms are words that meant something different in the past. "Fair" is questionable, by the way.

As I have already mentioned in my comment, Shakespeare's vocabulary is probably the best source for those (as well as the other category). Words such as "ability" (bodily power), "honest" (not promiscuous), "stout" (brave), "indifferent" (casual), "ramp" (whore) all seem to fall into that category.

As for ***grammatical*** archaisms, well, thou, thee, art (rather than "are"), hath, couldst, wouldst, mine (instead of "my", before a word beginning with a vowel), plus the entire collection of subjunctives, seem to fit the bill.

Here's one sight that might prove helpful:

http://www.shakespeareswords.com/Glossary?let=a

However, the web is chock-full of pages treating of Shakespeare's vocabulary.

I hope this helps.